# How to increase height of EditText as per text length dynamically in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to increase height of EditText  as per I write text in edittext dynamically or through xml .

I have tried this code but it increse up to 2 line. so help me out solve this.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtAddress"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:maxLength ="2000" 
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:background="@color/editText_line" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How many lines do you want to increase?

Comment: You are `height="wrap_content"` so you don't have to do any thing else, it will automatically  expend as per content height

Comment: Man i tried your code. It is increasing the height dynamically!!!

Comment: hi Mayuri , i want to add 4 lines in edittext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think implementing [android-autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) is the best possible solution to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 9):

It's better practice to **increase height of EditText upto 4 lines**. So you should try below code.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtInput"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:hint="Address"
    android:maxLength ="2000" 
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:maxLines="4" />
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                getSize();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getSize() {
        if (editText.getLineCount() == editText.getMaxLines()) {
            editText.setMaxLines((editText.getLineCount() + 1));
        }
        // Log.e("lenth", editText.getContentDescription().length()+"");

    }
}
```

Comment: That is working perfectly to increase the height when a line is added, but it doesn't reduce the height when a line is removed. To do so, set `maxLines` to `2` (or 1 more than the original number of lines) and `setMaxLines()` to `getLineCount() + 1` when `getMaxLines() != getLineCount() + 1` in `afterTextChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to set up:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score -1):

Set "android:maxLines" parameter to edittext in xml file, it will increase lines.

Answer (score -1):

Add this properties in your `EditText` in xml file:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:maxLines="10"
```